# Is land ownership traditionally considered a status symbol in Judaism?

Tags: history, real-estate

I'm writing a paper for a Jewish Film class about the the movie *The Apprenticeship of Duddy Kravitz*, and there is a scene in the beginning where Duddy's Zayda tells him "A man without land is nothing." I know that within the *tanach* the different tribes would own portions of land within Israel, but **is the concept of land ownership (outside of Israel) as a status symbol traditionally a Jewish concept?**
(my Initial thought was that it might be due to the fact that traditionally, Jews weren't allowed to own land in Europe, so a Jewish land owner would be considered especially high status, but I wasn't sure.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely a paraphrase of the Talmudic statement (Yevamos [63a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=63&format=pdf)):

> ואמר רבי אלעזר כל אדם שאין לו קרקע אינו אדם שנא׳ השמים שמים לה׳ והארץ נתן לבני אדם
>
> Rabbi Elazar said: "Every man who does not have land is not a man, as it says "[The heavens are heavens of G-d, but the earth He gave to the children of men.](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16336#showrashi=true&v=16)"